# how to parse a lot of PDFs

Tags: database, pdf-parsing

I have a ton of PDFs I want to be able to parse sentence-by-sentence. Is there a tool for MySQL (or some other database system) for converting PDFs into mysql, and then reading out sentences one at a time? Is there some other tool to do this? I imagined loading all the pdfs into a DB and then reading would be the fastest way but I don't really know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [pdftotext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext). Then insert it into DB.